# How pass suplier from kotlin?

Tags: java-8, kotlin, supplier

Look at the code:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync({
    awsBatch.terminateJob(
        TerminateJobRequest.builder().jobId(it).reason("terminated").build())}, executor)
```

Intellij get me:

```
Type mismatrch:
Required: Supplier<TerminateJobResponse>
Found: () -> TerminateJobResponse
```

While this compile perfect but without executor:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
    awsBatch.terminateJob(TerminateJobRequest.builder().jobId(it).reason("terminated").build())
}
```

How to pass Supplier to java 8 API from kotlin?

**Offtop (just my mood for today)**

They created a nice method `CompletableFuture.allOf()` with return type `void`, and created this - pass supplier as **first** argument...
I love java but all of this makes me berserk sometimes - why just not to look at scala and creates something the same??? Kotlin, scala
automatically expose second argument as function like `myFunc("parameter"){"function"}`. So now I have created a code and must 
spend couple hours for compilation some sugar (which should save my time instead)
:(((

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier<TerminateJobResponse> {
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Use Function Literals

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync<Something>({ Runnable { println("abc") } }, { Runnable { println("xyz") } })
```

See [SAM Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)